# Hold splashscreen with launch-screen

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, meteor

I've tried everything and I can't get https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/launch-screen to work.

I'd like to hold the Android's splashscreen with `var handle = LaunchScreen.hold();` but it doesn't seem to affect my app at all.

I tried to put it in different folders of my application (root, client root...), to wrap it with Meteor.startup, to use multiple handles, to put it in my iron-router... No chance yet.

Then I started to play with mobile-config since I suspected the config.xml to be the source of my problem. I tried to change "AutoHideSplashScreen" to true (meh, you never know...), to change the delay... It doesn't work either.

Finally, I took a shot at deleting completely the "launch-screen" package, but even when it doesn't appear with "meteor list", it's still there when I inspect my Android application. Maybe it needed to be overriden...

Anyway, I really need your help, thanks a lot !

EDIT : samples of my code

in /both/routes.js

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate : 'mainLayout',
    loadingTemplate: 'launchScreen',
    // Transitions
    // TODO : Use CSS or transition.js ? Slide or fade ?
    onBeforeAction : function(){
        $('.container').css({opacity: 0});
        this.next();
    },
    onAfterAction : function(){
        $('.container').transition({ opacity: 1 });
    }
});

// Routes
Router.map(function() {
    this.route('home', {path: '/'});
    this.route('news', {path: '/news'});
});
```

And if I try to put :

```
var handle = LaunchScreen.hold();
```

Anywhere in a file located in /client/*, it doesn't do anything.

Nothing special at the moment in my mobile-config, I deleted everything I tried...

```
// Allow XMLHttpRequest
App.accessRule("*");
```

Comment: please post your work.

Comment: I posted samples of my work but I don't know if it's really relevant... Now that I think about it, may the problem be because of my onBefore and onAfter on my routes.js ? May it prevent the package from working properly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems like I figured out a hack arround this for now. 
I added App.setPreference("SplashScreenDelay", 90000); in my mobile-config.js, since I noticed that even if the splashscreen is on hold, if the delay is out, its fades anyway.

It's hacky but I'll deal with it for now. :/

Answer (score 1):

You have to put `var handle = LaunchScreen.hold();` at the very "beginning" of your client code so it is loaded before everything else.

To do this you can put it in a file located in the **yourApp/client/lib/** folder (loaded before every other folders) and name the file with an underscore as files are loaded in alphabetical order.

Comment: Still no luck, I put it in yourApp/client/lib/ _init.js and the splashscreen still fades according to the config.xml file.